# Differences in C++ and Ada during static binding

Tags: c#, c++, binding, ada

I am in middle of my assignment and i came across this question:

> Assuming that we sometimes want static binding, do you prefer the method-by-method
>   approach of C++ and C#, or the variable-by-variable approach of Ada 95?Why?

I searched online and textbook, but i could not find what is the the meaning of method-by-method approach in C++ or variable-by-variable approach in Ada. Can anyone tell me the meaning of those terms and which is better out of those two approaches.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dispatching in Ada is discussed [here](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p2-4.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look at an example, C++ first:

```c
class Base {
public:
    void a();
    virtual void b();
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void a();
    virtual void b();
};

Base* base = new Base();
Derived* derived = new Derived();
Base* upcastedDerived = new Derived();

base->a(); // calls Base::a()
base->b(); // calls Base::b()

derived->a(); // calls Derived::a()
derived->b(); // calls Derived::b()

upcastedDerived->a(); // calls Base::a()
upcastedDerived->b(); // calls Derived::b()
```

Calling the methods of `base` and `derived` yields obvious results. On `upcastedDerived`, the call to `a()` is bound at compile-time (static binding), so it is bound to `Base::a()` because the variable has the type `Base*`. The call to `b()` however is bound at run-time, because the method is declared `virtual`. Because the object is actually of class `Derived`, `Derived::b()` gets called.

As you see, in C++ it depends on the method declaration whether the method call is bound statically or dynamically. Note that the keyword `virtual` in the derived class is optional - the method is automatically virtual because the base method it overrides is virtual.

Now let's do something similar with Ada:

```
procedure Dispatching is
   type Base is tagged null record;

   procedure A (Object : in out Base);

   type Derived is new Base with null record;

   overriding procedure A (Object : in out Derived);

   Base_Var : Base;
   Derived_Var : Derived;
   Upcasted_Var : Base'Class := Derived_Var;
begin
   A (Base_Var); -- calls first A() procedure
   A (Derived_Var); -- calls second A() procedure
   A (Upcasted_Var); -- calls second A() procedure
end Derived;
```

The first thing to note: Ada does not have a keyword similar to `virtual`. All methods can be bound statically or dynamically. As you see, it depends on the type of the object variable: `Base_Var` and `Derived_Var` both have a concrete type and thus the procedure of that type is called. `Upcasted_Var`, on the other hand, has a class-wide type (this has no equivalent in C++). Therefore, the third call to `A()` is bound dynamically.

To sum up: C++ (and C#) have a way to annotate to a method whether it should be dispatching or not. Ada has a way to annotate to an object variable whether calls to its functions should be dispatching or not. To control whether a call is dispatching or not, you can cast the variable to the class-wide type in Ada (you shouldn't cast to the concrete type to prevent dispatching, because if you already have a class-wide type, you cannot be sure whether you can cast it).

You can see it like this: in C++, any pointer-to-class type is class-wide. In Ada, any primitive subroutine of a tagged type is virtual. For completeness, here is how you can prevent dispatching based on a variable in C++:

```
upcastedDerived.Base::b();
```

I will not discuss which of these is the *better* approach, because that's primarily opinion-based.

Comment: There's also the option of using class-wide parameters.